# CoreOS access from other instance

Tags: coreos

I have a coreOS cluster with 3 instances. I need to init a service in the 3 instances, but I don't want to use the IP to connect. Is there a dynamic way to scan the instances and get the IP's and then use it?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following command to get a list of the cluster instances for further processing:

```
fleetctl list-machines | awk '{print $2}' | tail -n +2
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use the IP in one of your containers/services, and you're running CoreOS on a cloud providers, you can source in an environment file with the allocated IPs:

`[Service]
EnvironmentFile=/etc/environment`

and then use those values as environment variables.

Answer (score 1):

CoreOS has a built in scheduler called `fleet` that runs on all hosts. You can just create the service and execute the command to run the service:
`fleetctl start myunit.service`.

To tail the output of the service you can run: `fleetctl journal -f myunit.service` which will automatically ssh into the host running the container, and see the output.

"I need to init a service in the 3 instances"
It seems like you're trying to run a service that should be active on all hosts in the CoreOS cluster. [Take a look at the X-Fleet variable Global](https://coreos.com/fleet/docs/latest/unit-files-and-scheduling.html). You can set up a service to run on all hosts by adding this to the bottom of your service/unit file:

```
[X-Fleet]
Global=true
```

This way you will only have to start the service once, to initiate it on all hosts in the CoreOS cluster.